# Build folder is not exist in github action for outlook web add-in using react

Tags: reactjs, github, amazon-s3, continuous-integration, github-actions

I create outlook web add-in using react and yo office tool. I have commit code in GitHub repo. I want add git actions that allow us automatic upload build folder content to S3 bucket via github actions.
My action yaml file as following

```
name: Pre-dev branch

 on:
  push:
  branches: [ "pre-dev" ]
 pull_request:
branches: [ "pre-dev" ]

 jobs:
  build:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest

strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [15.x]

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
  - run: npm install
  - run: npm run build      
  - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
    with:
      args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
    env:
      AWS_S3_BUCKET: 'shyam-pre-dev'
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_REGION: 'eu-west-1'   # optional: defaults to us-east-1
      SOURCE_DIR: 'dist'      # optional: defaults to entire repository
```

Update :
My project package.json file content:

```
 "scripts": {
"build": "webpack --mode production",
"build:dev": "webpack --mode development",
"dev-server": "webpack serve --mode development",
"lint": "office-addin-lint check",
"lint:fix": "office-addin-lint fix",
"prettier": "office-addin-lint prettier",
"start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",
"start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
"start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web",
"stop": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest.xml",
"validate": "office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml",
"watch": "webpack --mode development --watch"
}
```

once I commit code it is executing and give error 'Build folder is not exists.
Anyone has any idea. Please help me.

Comment: Do you get the same results with a regular react-based web application? How is it related to web add-ins?

Comment: It is working in simple react app. Sample is here https://github.com/shahshyam/react-actions/blob/master/.github/workflows/workflow.yml

Comment: What is the difference between a sample react and your add-in web app? Have you used webpack in your sample react app?

Comment: No, I have not used it. When I have run locally build command ,Outlook web addin create build folder. So, I think, web pack will not create any issue.

Comment: You think, but worth checking everything.

Comment: It is solved by using 'dist' folder instead of using 'build'

Comment: Good! I was on the right avenue. Don't forget to mark the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between a webpack-based web application and react one. The output folder is different.